# Lossless Compression and definition of Entropy

Tags: computer-science, information-theory, entropy

I am taking an intro class to Information Theory and I have a question. Suppose we have three symbols `a, b, and c` with probabilities of them coming out of a chanell with `0.7, 0.15 and 0.15` respectively.

If we take 2 bits for each character we can encode them like  below.

`a - 0
b  - 11
c - 10`

With this encoding we get expected number of bits per source symbol is `1.3`.

However, if we try to encode two symbols at a time in an attempt to find a better average bit per symbol we can do this:

`aa - 00
ab - 100
ac - 111
ba - 101
ca - 1100
bb - 110100
bc - 110101
cb - 110110
cc - 110111`

With this encoding scheme the expected number of bits per source is: `1.1975`.

My question is, if we use the above encoding then how do we represent `a, b and c` considering it is a two-symbol encoding?

Thanks.

Comment: In the first case, I think you meant `a - 0` instead of `a - 00`.

Comment: Please try to write more clearly.  To start, re-read your first sentence—a classic run-on—and break it into grammatical sentences.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Sure.

Comment: "how do we represent a, b and c" You mean, how do we represent a single symbol ? Or the sequence "abc" ? Or what?

Comment: Also, the title is not very descriptive of the question (this is not a about definition of Entropy)

Comment: @leonbloy Yes, a single a or a single b or a single c.

Answer (score 0):

The question seems to be: when encoding the $2-$extension of a source, how do we encode a message consisting of just one (original, not extended) symbol? (Or, for that matter, an odd number of symbols?)

This is an implementation detail, which has no single/elegant/interesting answer. It's not very interesting because the theory of compression (in particular, Shannon first theorem, which implies that by coding the $m-$extension of a stationary memoryless source we approach the entropy for large $m$) is only valid/relevant asympotically, for large $n$ (total length of the message).

But how can we do it? Well, for example, by prepending to the coded sequence a (suitable coded) integer that signals the total number of (original, not extended) symbols included. In that way, we could encode the single (or last) symbol (say, `a`) using the code for (say) `ab`. The decoder will know that the last `b` is mere stuffing, and will discard it.

Sure, this will degrade the compression, but asymptotically, it does not matter.

There are other methods: add to the list of extended symbols an extra dummy symbol "EOF" (end of file, end of message), and assign to it a low probability. Again, the paragraph above applies.

(In a sense, the question is similar to this one: we know how to store and retrieve one byte, (or two, or three...) in the computer disk, by creating a file. Now, can we store 12 bits (one byte and a half)? Answer: we surely can, but the reader must know (either implicitly, or by reading some extra data, perhaps as a file preface) the total number of bits.)